# Why does RSA encryption error with RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256?

Tags: .net, .net-core, cryptography

The following code works.

```
        var plainText = "abc";
        var plainBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);

        var rsaParams = new RSAParameters();
        rsaParams.Modulus = Convert.FromBase64String("...");
        rsaParams.Exponent = Convert.FromBase64String("...");
        var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
        rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParams);
        var actualEncryptedBytes = rsa.Encrypt(plainBytes, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA1);
```

But following does not work and errors with "Specified padding mode is not valid for this algorithm.". Why?

```
        var plainText = "abc";
        var plainBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);

        var rsaParams = new RSAParameters();
        rsaParams.Modulus = Convert.FromBase64String("...");
        rsaParams.Exponent = Convert.FromBase64String("...");
        var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
        rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParams);
        var actualEncryptedBytes = rsa.Encrypt(plainBytes, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);
```

Comment: [`RSACryptoServiceProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider?view=netframework-4.8) only supports PKCS#1 v1.5-padding and OAEP with SHA-1. The support of OAEP with SHA-2 is only realized for the newer RSA-implementation, [`RSACng`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacng?view=netframework-4.8) (available since .NET 4.6), which belongs to the new [Cryptography API (Next Generation)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecCNG/cng-portal).

Comment: RSACng works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Topaco above, the following code works:

```
        var rsaParams = new RSAParameters();
        rsaParams.Modulus = Convert.FromBase64String("...");
        rsaParams.Exponent = Convert.FromBase64String("...");
        var rsa = RSA.Create(rsaParams);
        var actualEncryptedBytes = rsa.Encrypt(plainBytes, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);
```